# Python not running subprocess command due to filename being too long

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following python command to run the subprocess `gdal_grid` with previously specified variables as the configurations

```
subprocess.call(f'gdal_grid -a nearest:radius1={cell_size}:radius2={cell_size}:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe {txextent} -tye {tyextent} -tr {resolution} -zfield z {shapefile} {output_file}.tif')
```

However, I keep receiving the error `ERRNO 36 File name too long` for the `output_file`
It is named using the input filename so is like so ... `2022_TestData_TrialNo2_Survey_25m_BD_ITM_Zvalue.tif`

As a result, the output file isn't being created.

I need to get past this error in order to create the output file, but I don't know how

Comment: have you tried giving it a shorter name (and maybe later renaming the file)?

Comment: What OS/Filesystem is that? 52 characters doesn't seem that long to me.

Comment: what are the values of all the vars in your f-string?

Comment: @Sören Running on windows

Comment: @Anentropic ```gdal_grid -a nearest:radius1=1.0:radius2=1.0:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe 717134 728448 -tye 732481 734667 -tr 1.0 1.0 -zfield z 2022_TestData_TrialNo2_Survey_25m_BD_ITM_Zvalue.shp 2022_TestData_TrialNo2_Survey_25m_BD_ITM_Zvalue.tif```

Comment: not sure if it will help but try passing a list of individual args instead of a single long string, as described here https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen